# Traffic distribution inside an GCP instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google, gcp

I have a *regional instance group* with 2 instances serving on port 8000, no autoscaling enabled.

This instance group is the backend of a *Global external application load balancer*.

The web server on the instances is running flask and each request will take 1 second to process:

```python
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def main() -> Response:
    sleep(1)
    response = jsonify(
        success=True,
        hostname=gethostname(),
    )
    response.status_code = 200
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    return response
```

I can confirm the behaviour by hitting the global load balancer public ip, ie takes 1 sec to get a response.

If I run 2 request at the same time, as there are 2 instances, I am expecting that each request will go to a different instance instead they always go to the same instance and they are queued on it, so:

- one request will take 1 sec
- the other request will take 2 sec

I have tried to change the `Locality load balancing policy` to `Round-Robin`, `Least-Request` and `Random`, but I always get the same behaviour.

Am I understanding correctly that `Locality load balancing policy` is only about which backend will be chosen? If yes how do you configure the load balancing policy inside a backend (ie instance group)?

Thanks

## Configuration

### Instance group

- Regional
- Target distribution shape: Even
- [x] Allow instance redistribution
- Autoscaling on: min 2, max 2
- Autoscaling signal: HTTP load-balancing 100%
- Initialisation period: 60s
- Health check:

  - Path: /health
  - Protocol: HTTP
  - Port: 8000
  - Interval: 30 sec
  - Timeout: 30 sec
  - Healthy threshold: 1
  - Unhealthy threshold: 10

### Load balancer

- Frontend:

  - Protocol: HTTP
  - IP: x.x.x.x
  - Network Tier: Premium
  - HTTP keepalive timeout: 610 sec
- Routing rules: All unmatched
- Backend services:

  - Endpoint protocol: HTTP
  - Named port: web
  - Timeout: 300 seconds
  - Cloud CDN: Disabled
  - Logging: Enabled (sample rate: 1)
  - Session affinity: None
  - Connection draining timeout: 300 seconds
  - Traffic policy:

    - Locality load balancing policy: Round robin
    - Outlier detection: Disabled
  - Backend security policy: None
  - Edge security policy: None
  - Identity-Aware Proxy: Disabled
- Balancing mode: Max. RPS: 1 (per instance)
- Capacity: 100%

## Test

```bash
siege \
    --concurrent 1 \
    --time 60s \
    "http://x.x.x.x"
```

With 2 nodes:

- `concurrent=1`: avg 1.02 sec
- `concurrent=2`: avg 1.66 sec
- `concurrent=4`: avg 3.35 sec
- `concurrent=8`: avg 5.54 sec

With 4 nodes:

- `concurrent=1`: avg 1.02 sec
- `concurrent=2`: avg 1.18 sec
- `concurrent=4`: avg 2.70 sec
- `concurrent=8`: avg 3.83 sec
- `concurrent=16`: avg 7.26 sec

With 8 nodes:

- `concurrent=2`: avg 1.20 sec
- `concurrent=4`: avg 1.85 sec
- `concurrent=16`: avg 4.40 sec
- `concurrent=64`: avg 14.06 sec
- `concurrent=128`: avg 19.04 sec

## Expected behaviour

I would have assumed results like:

- 2 nodes:

  - `concurrent=1`: 1 sec
  - `concurrent=2`: 1 sec
  - `concurrent=4`: ~2 sec
  - `concurrent=8`: ~4 sec
- 4 nodes:

  - `concurrent=1`: 1 sec
  - `concurrent=2`: 1 sec
  - `concurrent=4`: 1 sec
  - `concurrent=8`: ~2 sec
  - `concurrent=16`: ~4 sec

## Update 1

If I switch to a `Classic proxy network load balancer` and I send 100 requests:

- 56 go to vm0
- 44 go to vm1

Instead for an HTTP LB:

- 99 go to vm0
- 1 go to vm1

Comment: We need more details on the backend configuration, instance group, instance zones, session affinity, etc. Note: try testing with a large load and post the results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have just updated the main post

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Global external Application Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#classic-global-td) GFE (Google Front End) estimates which backend instances have capacity to receive requests. You can scan the link shared to know more about the distribution of traffic.

If you think round-robin is not working for you, I would suggest to use [balancing mode](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#balancing-mode) wherein the concept or configuration is to distribute traffic evenly.

I also found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700723/google-cloud-load-balancer-algorithm-round-robin) a question from stackoverflow that might be helpful from using balancing mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I think that the settings I am looking is `SPRAY_TO_REGION`. Is it available in terraform?

Comment: Could you check my update?

Comment: I think its not available in terraform though you can still configure it, you can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/service-lb-policy#create_a_policy) as a guidance.